# Barcode Scanner handler

Tags: vb.net, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am dealing with barcodes and I need some help

Is there some kinds of events or handlers for barcode scanners (maybe something like onScanFinished) in VB.NET?

I don't want to use textboxs, it doesn't work for me.

I need it to show me the scan result in a MsgBox. Is that possible ?

Comment: Trying to get into the context of where you are.  Can you post the code with the textboxes or what you have tried so far?

Comment: I suggest you look at your barcode reader manufacturer's website. I think Motorolla do have an API for .NET CF. Other than that, as of now I don't think there is any native API for barcode scanners in the .NET Framework itself.

Comment: If the scanner is an HID device, you shouldn't need any special code to read the output from it.  Any control that accepts text will accept the output from the scanner.  Basically whatever string the scanner decodes the barcode to, will be entered the same as typing it on a keyboard.

Comment: guys thank you for commenting, i edited the post, could you read it again please.

Answer (score 0):

## I solved it

```
Public Class Form1
Dim aaa As String = ""
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.SpaceThen 'or the character that comes at the end of the scanned barcode
        MsgBox(aaa)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    aaa = aaa & e.KeyChar.ToString
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

End Class